# How to stream audio from nodejs server to android

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io, audio-streaming

We are working on a mobile app that requires songs streamed from the server to the android client. We are using socket.io for all the functionalities of the app and its working great !
The audio files are stored on the server and need to be streamed to the android client. I came across this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream
But it doesn't seem to have a client library for Java/Android

Can you suggest any method to stream audio ?

Comment: its just plain binary you need to handle the binary data in Android. Buffer the data and play the audio. You could also just use media player and provide the url that streams the file to client. You can find many examples for MediaPlayer or how to play audio from http streaming server. Personally I would choose to authenticate access to http server streaming and only serve UI interactions using socket.io